# How to generate multiple flexdashboards in R filtering Quarters

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am trying to generate multiple flexdashboards in R, the outfile format is .html, I am able to generate one output at a time based on Quarters entered manually. But I was hoping if there is an easier way to do it using **for loops** to filter the data quarterly and then generate separate flexdashboard outputs

This is where i am manually changing the date range

```
title = "Q1 2019"
FromDt = "2019-01-01"
ToDt = "2019-03-31"


data_subset<- data%>% select(a,b,c,d,e)%>%
  filter(Date1 >= as.Date(FromDt) & Date1 <= as.Date(ToDt)) %>%
  collect()
```

I am using a separate R file for rendering the dashboard.

```
rmarkdown::render("Q012019.Rmd")
```

This will create a subset of data with the first Quarter of 2019.

What I want is

```
FromDt = "2017-01-01"
ToDt = "2019-03-31"
```

Which will automatically subset the data and  generate multiple flexdashboards based on each quarter.

Comment: This sounds like a case where [parameterized reports](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html) would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am trying to read on it and see if is possible for me to do it with parameterized report. I will post an update just in case I was able to find something.